# Search an entire sheet to return the cell that is an exact match (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to search an entire sheet to find the cell that is an exact match for a cell in the current sheet

I have used the following to return the last cell in the 'Dropdowns' sheet *containing* the string in B1, but I need the match to be *exact*:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ADDRESS(LARGE(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,Dropdowns!A:Z))*ROW(Dropdowns!A:Z),1),LARGE(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,Dropdowns!A:Z))*COLUMN(Dropdowns!A:Z),1)))
```

Here is a link to my test Google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZvGN9vYKT2qPgg5CFa-9Cgec2EDFH1bGXCTysTLLbWU/edit#gid=0

In this sheet you can see that 'Push Press' (B1) appears 3 times in the 'Dropdowns' sheet:

1. Dumbbell Push Press (C17)
2. Push Press (C22)
3. Standing Barbell Push Press (H53)

The formula above returns $H$53, the last instance of the string

Should I perhaps be using the query function instead?

Comment: Whats the ideal expected output in this sample scenario?!

Comment: If you just want to find where certain text strings are, why not use **Edit > Find and replace > Match entire cell contents**?

Comment: @rockinfreakshow C22 - Exact match

Comment: @doubleunary I have a much more complicated sheet that first finds the matching value in a hidden sheet and then displays the value of the cell next to it. Currently it only works for strings that are unique, unlike 'Push Press' which appears 3 times

Comment: In that case, you do not need to collect cell locations. There are better ways to get the contents of a cell next to a particular value. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)

Comment: @doubleunary you are quite right, I should have asked for guidance on getting the actual value required (the adjacent cell) instead of trying to break down my crappy formula into parts! Appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(Σ,indirect("Dropdowns!1:"&rows(Dropdowns!A:A)),
       tocol(makearray(rows(Σ),columns(Σ),lambda(r,c,if(index(Σ,r,c)=B1,address(r,c,4),))),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic @rockinfreakshow, that returns C22 as required!